# Tomcat: Difference Between "webapps/" folder and "webapps/ROOT/" folder

Tags: java, tomcat, path, reload

I have noticed that these folders have very different properties. I have recently deployed a .war file under the webapps folder. I have noticed that, once the .war file had been deployed, an uncompressed version of the project was added to the directory. When I try to modify any files in the uncompressed version, the Tomcat server does not change the behaviour of my application (I cannot see the change when running my application through the web browser). However, if I put this same project under webapps/ROOT, a change in my application will result in an instantaneous change in the behaviour of my application (which can be seen through the browser).

Here is another example. I currently have the HTTP 415 error on some application. When I get it deployed using a .war file under the folder webapps, I get that error. However, if I put the uncompressed version of the application under webapps/ROOT, the error disappears and my application is working perfectly.

This brings me to my question. How are these two folders different? What can explain these differences between these folders?

Comment: `webapps` is where web applications are deployed. `ROOT` is a special name for the unnamed root web application. E.g. web application with context `/Foo` is in `webapps/Foo.war` and/or `webapps/Foo/` folder. Web application with context `/` is in `webapps/ROOT.war` and/or `webapps/ROOT/` folder.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you. How can this explain the fact that the webapps/ROOT/ folder gets updated as soon as I change something in my code, and that web applications directly under the webapps/ folder do not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having tried different things, this is what I have found:

I realized that the folder webapps is the folder defined as being the 'appBase' of the server. (This variable can be configured in the server.xml file, located in the conf folder, which is seen from the root file of your apache tomcat) In other words, it serves as the direct location where Tomcat searches for application.

What is not told, however, is that Tomcat does not go into the folders; which is why my web applications could get updated and receive errors under webapps, but not under ROOT. I know this because I changed the 'appBase' variable directly to where my applications were and suddenly they were showing errors from tomcat.

If changes are made to a web application under the 'appBase' defined path, they need to be reloaded a specific way. One is to use Tomcat Manager feature, and the other is to delete the files in your work folder (found from your main Apache Tomcat folder. keep clicking into folders from the work folder until you get to your web application's main folder). The Tomcat Manager feature can be a more tedious task to implement, because one needs to know about how to configure users for tomcat (in tomcat-users.xml, found under the conf folder), and documentation for this is limited. The second solution, which is to delete your web application found under the work folder, can be done while tomcat is running and will implement your changes in the instant.

More details are found on another Stack Overflow post: [How to force tomcat to reload recently compiled class/war files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765493/how-to-force-tomcat-to-reload-recently-compiled-class-war-files)